# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user' Django

Tags: python, django

When i submit form i get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user' please help meto fix this problem

My forms.py

```
class resume_upload(forms.ModelForm):
    cv = forms.FileField(required = True)
    job_title = forms.CharField(required = True)

    def save(self, commit=False):
       cvs = super(resume_upload, self).save(commit=False)
       cvs.cv = self.cleaned_data['cv']
       cvs.job_title = self.cleaned_data['job_title']

       if commit:
           cvs.save()


    class Meta:
        model = Cv
        fields = ('cv', 'job_title',)
```

My models.py

```
class Cv(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     cv = models.FileField(upload_to='cvs', default='', validators=[validate_file_extension])
     job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title
```

and my views.py

```
def upload_resume(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = resume_upload(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            cv_form = form.save() # commit is False in this case.
            cv_form.user = request.user
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request,"Oops! That didn't work. Please try again")
    else:
        form = resume_upload()
    return render(request, 'upload_resume.html',{'form':form,})
```

Comment: Your view is wrongly indented. Please fix that.

Comment: yes that is when i write the code here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you overwrite the `save()` method in your ModelForm `resume_upload(forms.ModelForm)` you need to return the object:

```
def save(self, commit=False):
    cvs = super(resume_upload, self).save(commit=False)
    cvs.cv = self.cleaned_data['cv']
    cvs.job_title = self.cleaned_data['job_title']

    if commit:
        cvs.save()

    return cvs
```

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding your user field when you setting up fields that way, so they cant find attribute user in your form when you trying to pass `request.user` to it

```
class Meta:
    model = Cv
    fields = ('cv', 'job_title', 'user')
```

Comment: Thank but i fix it with the previous answer